# Sql Procedimento

Tags: sql

Boa tarde, alguém me pode ajudar a criar um procedimento na base de dados em SQL ?
Para fazer uma reserva de um quarto, eu tenho que selecionar um quarto e declarar a DataEntrada  e a DataSaida.

O que pretendo, é se fizer uma reserva no quarto 1 entres os dias 13/06/2018 e 14/06/2018, e depois se alguém quiser fazer outra reserva nesse mesmo quarto entre os dias 13/06/2018 e 14/06/2018, dado que esse quarto já possui uma reserva nesse dia, eu quero que apareça uma mensagem a dizer ocupado. Alguém me consegue ajudar?

**Tabela reserva**

```
 public partial class Reserva
    {
        public int ID_Reserva { get; set; }
        public int ID_Cliente { get; set; }
        public int ID_Quarto { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DataEntrada { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataSaida { get; set; }
        public int NumeroPessoas { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> NumeroNoites { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Preço { get; set; }
        public string Observaçoes { get; set; }

        public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
        public virtual Quarto Quarto { get; set; }
    }
```

**Tabela Quarto**

```
public partial class Quarto
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Quarto()
    {
        this.Reserva = new HashSet<Reserva>();
    }

    public int ID_Quarto { get; set; }
    public string TipoQuarto { get; set; }
    public string EstadoQuarto { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> PreçoQuarto { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Reserva> Reserva { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Você precisa fornecer algumas informações a mais para que possamos ajudar. A primeira é qual o `SGBD` que você está utilizando. `SQL Server`? A segunda é informar quais tabelas estão envolvidas nessa reserva.

Comment: Tu precisa utilizar a cláusula BETWEEN e informar a data de saída e entrada, considerando que esteja usando SQL. Já existem preguntas respondidas sobre isso.

Comment: @Sorack obrigado pela resposta. Estou a usar SQL Server . Editei a pergunta e pode ver as tabelas, cumprimentos.

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar um procedimento como o exemplificado a seguir:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reservar(@id_quarto    INT,
                          @data_entrada DATE,
                          @data_saida   DATE)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @dias TABLE(dia DATE);

  -- Gera um registro para cada dia dentro do período de datas escolhido
  WITH dias AS (
    SELECT @data_entrada AS dia
     UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, d.dia)
      FROM dias d
     WHERE d.dia < @data_saida
  )
  INSERT INTO @dias(dia)
  SELECT d.dia
    FROM dias d;

  -- Verifica se existe uma reserva para algum dos dias que foi informado
  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
              FROM reserva r
             INNER JOIN @dias d ON d.dia BETWEEN r.data_entrada AND r.data_saida
             WHERE r.id_quarto = @id_quarto)
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Já existe uma reserva para a data informada no quarto desejado', 16, 1);
    RETURN;
  END;

  INSERT INTO reserva(id_quarto, data_entrada, data_saida)
               VALUES(@id_quarto, @data_entrada, @data_saida);
END;
GO
```

No procedimento acima geramos uma lista de dias dentro do intervalo informado e buscamos uma reserva que tenha conflito com a data e quarto escolhido. Caso não ocorra conflito nestes termos, um registro é inserido na tabela `reserva`.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda! está-me a dar erro no parêntese daqui  `RAISERROR('Já existe uma reserva para a data informada no quarto desejado');` a datas estão no formato "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" e em nada irá atrapalhar certo?

Comment: @Heftysilva havia esquecido alguns parâmetros. Tente dessa forma

Comment: executei sem qualquer erro. Agora para implementar esse procedimento, tenho que atualizar o modelo, carregar o procedimento e associa-lo a tabela reserva? estou a usar MVC